# Angular.js working on one element, but on one very similiar not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Here's my code: 'http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/NAkdKR'. I use there restricted API, but you can access it by f.e. using Allow-Control-Allow-Origin Chrome extention. My code should display currencies when I choose countries from both `<select>` lists, but only the first works.

When the app launches, the first country is set to Wielka Brytania (Great Britain) and the currency below is set to GBP. The second country is set to Polska (Poland) and the currency below is PLN (as it should be). When I change first country to Poland, the currency below updates to PLN. But when I try to change the second country, the currency changes to EUR no matter what country I choose, and that's the problem

I'm new to Angular and it's very confusing for me, I would be grateful if someone could point what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What your error exactly? I'm trying it from my place and when I choose from both country list the currencies combo are both updated.

Comment: When I choose the first country, the first <select> with currency abbreviation should update and this works ok, but when I choose the second country, the second currency abbrev doesn't update.

Comment: When I select the second county A request is sent looking like this : `https://www.easysend.pl/api/calculator/currencies/2/1` This returns me an Json with several records and the second select is updated with all the records that are in this json. That's what I'm seeing here.

Comment: That's right, the second country selection depends on the first one. And it works ok. The problem is that when I choose the second country, the currency below for this country doesn't update.

Comment: Could you give me an example: What's your input, what you get and what you expected?

Comment: I changed the app language to English, so you could understand what I'm trying to get

Comment: When the app launches, the first country is set to Wielka Brytania (Great Britain) and the currency below is set to GBP. The second country is set to Polska (Poland) and the currency below is PLN (as it should be). When I change first country to Poland, the currency below updates to PLN. But **when I try to change the second country, the currency changes to EUR no matter what country I choose, and that's the problem.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121895/discussion-between-eric-and-summerfreeze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store the destination you get back from your api

```
var destinations = {};
...
```

the in your response from `url: "https://www.easysend.pl/api/calculator/countries/" + selcountry + "/destinations"` store it

```
this.destinations = response.data;
```

Finaly when you are receiving the response from `"https://www.easysend.pl/api/calculator/currencies/" + selcountry + "/" + destination + ""`

instead of `$scope.currency2 = $scope.currency[0];` check the default currency in your destinations variable

```
angular.forEach(this.destinations,function(dest,key){
                if(dest.id == destination){

                    angular.forEach(response.data,function(currencyOption,key){
                        if(currencyOption.currency_out.id == dest.default_currency.id){
                            $scope.currency2 = currencyOption;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAkmJo?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Verify you selects::

```
 <select ng-options="item.name for item in countries" ng-model="selcountry" ng-change="countryincheck()">
              </select>
                                    <span>do</span>
                                        <select ng-model="destination" ng-change="destcheck()"  ng-options="item as item.name for item in destinations track by item.name">
                                        </select>
```

In first select, you are binding `item.name` to `selcountry` while in second select you are binding `item (object)`  to `destination` which will not work as item is not string here.

And you are appending it to url:

```
destination = $scope.destination.id;
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: "https://www.easysend.pl/api/calculator/currencies/" + selcountry + "/" + destination + "" })
                    .then(function successCallback(response) {
```

Just try to change your second select as below, it should work.

```
<select ng-model="destination" ng-change="destcheck()"  ng-options="item.name for item in destinations track by item.name">
                                            </select>
```